# Exclude module at gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have the following gradle file in my project:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'payment-gateway', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

The problem in that payment-gateway.aar is third party and contains an old version of library: idtech-card-reader-resources-v4.4.jar

At the same time we already are using new version of this librbary:
UniMag_SDK_v5.0.jar

So during compilation process I'm receiving the following error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   LIDTech/MSR/XMLManager/ConfigParameters;

Could someone help me to resolve conflict? How I can tell to exclude 'idtech-card-reader-resources-v4.4.jar' or to use latest version of library?

Answer (score 2):

```
compile(name:'payment-gateway', ext:'aar'){
  exclude module:'idtech-card-reader-resources'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But for some reason it doesn't help. I already tried different exclude options. But without success. Possibly module name is invalid. Is there a way to determine exact module name?

Comment: In order to get list of all exact dependencies names, use `gradlew dependencies`

Comment: I checked result of gradlew dependencies command. There is no mention anything connected to idtech.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling multidex in your build.gradle?

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```